# MySqli INSERT not working, no error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

My code seems to be correct. A form is displayed and then when the submit button is clicked this code is supposed to execute. If the article exist it ends and says so but it is not inserting into the database or giving an error or showing any printout if the article does not exist.

EDIT: provided whole form

```html
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    print '
<div class="container-fluid ui-widget">


<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="inputform.php" onsubmit="return confirm("Is all of your data correct?");">
<fieldset>

<!-- Article Input -->
<legend>Article Input</legend>

<!-- Journal Radio Buttons (value is journal ISSN)-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="journal_radio">Journal</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="journal_radio-0">
      <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-0" value="2162-9730" checked="checked">
      MIS Quarterly
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="journal_radio-1">
      <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-1" value="1047-7047">
      Information Systems Research
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="journal_radio-2">
      <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-2" value="0742-1222">
      Journal of Management Information Systems
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="journal_radio-3">
      <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-3" value="1536-9323">
      Journal of the Association for Information Systems
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="journal_radio-4">
      <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-4" value="1476-9344">
      European Journal of Information Systems
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="journal_radio-5">
      <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-5" value="1365-2575">
      Information Systems Journal
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="journal_radio-6">
      <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-6" value="0963-8687">
      Journal of Strategic Information Systems
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="journal_radio-7">
      <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-7" value="0268-3962">
      Journal of Information Technology
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="journal_radio-8">
      <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-8" value="0167-9236">
      Decision Support Systems
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="journal_radio-9">
      <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-9" value="0378-7206">
      Information and Management
    </label>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Article Name Input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="article_name">Article Name:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="article_name" name="article_name" type="text" placeholder="Article Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 1-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author1_name">Author 1:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author1_name" name="author1_name" type="text" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 1 University -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author1_university">University:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author1_university" name="author1_university" type="text" placeholder="Author University" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 2-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author2_name">Author 2:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author2_name" name="author2_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 2 University-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author2_university">University:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author2_university" name="author2_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 3-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author3_name">Author 3:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author3_name" name="author3_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 3 University-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author3_university">University:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author3_university" name="author3_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 4-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author4_name">Author 4: </label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author4_name" name="author4_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 4 University-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author4_university">University:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author4_university" name="author4_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 5-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author5_name">Author 5:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author5_name" name="author5_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 5 University-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author5_university">University:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author5_university" name="author5_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 6-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author6_name">Author 6:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author6_name" name="author6_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Author 6 University-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author6_university">University:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="author6_university" name="author6_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Year Published -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="year">Year Published</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control">
      <option value="2010">2010</option>
      <option value="2011">2011</option>
      <option value="2012">2012</option>
      <option value="2013">2013</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Is Security Checkbox -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="is_security"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="is_security-0">
      <input type="checkbox" name="is_security" id="is_security-0" value="1">
      Security Related
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Submit Form Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-4 control-label">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>


</div>';
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  
  $dbHost = "localhost";
  $dbUsername = "admin";
  $dbPassword = "";
  $dbName = "webdb";

  // Create connection
  $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
  // Check connection
  if ($db->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
  }

    $journal = $_POST['journal_radio'];
    $article_name = $_POST['article_name'];
    $author1 = $_POST['author1_name'];
    $author1uni = $_POST['author1_university'];
    $author2 = $_POST['author2_name'];
    $author2uni = $_POST['author2_university'];
    $author3 = $_POST['author3_name'];
    $author3uni = $_POST['author3_university'];
    $author4 = $_POST['author4_name'];
    $author4uni = $_POST['author4_university'];
    $author5 = $_POST['author5_name'];
    $author5uni = $_POST['author5_university'];
    $author6 = $_POST['author6_name'];
    $author6uni = $_POST['author6_university'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $security = $_POST['is_security'];

      //check if article exist
      $articlequery = $db->query("SELECT Article_Title FROM Articles WHERE Article_Title = '$article_name'");
      if($articlequery->num_rows != 0) {
           print 'Article Already Exists';
      } else {
  //insert if doesn't exit 
  $articleinsert = "INSERT INTO Articles (ISSN, Year_Published, Is_Security, Article_Title)
  VALUES ('$journal',$year,$security,'$article_name')";

  if ($db->query($articleinsert) === TRUE) {
  echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New record created successfully');</script>";
  } else {
  echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $articleinsert . "<br>" . $db->error."');</script>";
  }



          }
    $conn->close();
       
          
    }
          
?>
```

I've narrowed it down to this area but can't seem to find the issue...

```
$articleinsert = "INSERT INTO Articles (ISSN, Year_Published, Is_Security, Article_Title)
    VALUES ('$journal',$year,$security,'$article_name')";

    if ($db->query($articleinsert) === TRUE) {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New record created successfully');</script>";
    } else {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $articleinsert . "<br>" . $db->error."');</script>";
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your html form?

Comment: try to debug step by step first echo "SELECT Article_Title FROM Articles WHERE Article_Title = '$article_name" see what comes and copy n paste to sql and see whether record exist and then echo "INSERT INTO Articles (ISSN, Year_Published, Is_Security, Article_Title)
    VALUES ('$journal',$year,$security,'$article_name')" and same follow same process  as above and see if both query works in sql well, then it has to work for php... :)

Comment: I am able to run the statement inside of PHPMyAdmin and create the record by replacing variables with corresponding value. :/

Comment: It may be worth adding that this is just the beginning of mysql inserts. The extra variables are going to be used in other sql inserts

Comment: @dtj When I press submit and the article doesnt exit the output is just a white screen. Theres no insert that completes nor is there an error message.

Comment: ass `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, see if you are getting any errors...

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Thanks. That didn't return any errors. I get error reporting through host. Its just going to a white page when i click submit.

Comment: `echo $articlequery->num_rows;` and check what you are getting there...

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju That doesn't print anything. Not even 0. Just a blank white page. If the article is in the database it prints that it found the article. doesnt make any sense....

Comment: is it entering inside `if()`??

Comment: Use quotes for both $year and $security even if they are INT in the db

Comment: @Mihai That solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT Statement requires single quotes around all values/variables. Placed them around $journal and $year and the form was fully functional.

Thanks to @Mihai for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
$conn->close(); should be $db->close();
```

Comment: Ah I forgot to correct that on my post but that didn't correct the issue :/

Comment: echo $journal,$year,$security,$article_name and find what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Your Query

```
 INSERT INTO Articles (ISSN, Year_Published, Is_Security, Article_Title)
        VALUES ('$journal',$year,$security,'$article_name')
```

Change Into

```
INSERT INTO Articles (ISSN, Year_Published, Is_Security, Article_Title)
    VALUES ('".$journal."','".$year."','".$security."','".$article_name."')
```

I hope it will help you. Suppose it's also not working then,
Please check your input data's one by one.
Maybe it's wrong.
And also check your input data type (varchar length) in the database.